# remove None's by filter but not 0

Tags: python, filter, nonetype

I got a list of lists with integers and Nones.
I want to filter out only the Nones.

```
[int(all(sub)) for sub in zip(*lists_for_filtering)]
```

This removes the None's, BUT also the 0 (integer).
I want to modify it in the way to keep 0 (integer)

Result is a list list [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0] --> Nones result in 0, but also 0 results in 0 --> this should result in 1 because its not None

Comment: Care to show `lists_for_filtering` ?

Comment: [1,2,3,None,5,4,3,0,None] ... 4 lists like this.

Comment: Suppose, `lff = [[3, 0, None, 4], [6, 7, 0, None], [8, 0, 5, 6], [4, None, 8, 6]]`. You could use this list-comprehension to remove NoneTypes : `[[i for i in l if i!=None] for l in lff]`. Gives :
`[[3, 0, 4], [6, 7, 0], [8, 0, 5, 6], [4, 8, 6] ]`

Comment: Here's one possible solution: `[[int(x) for x in sub if x is not None] for sub in zip(*lists_for_filtering)]`. And by the way, using `zip` will transform your list structure, is this what you want on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is the all() function, that evaluates both 0 and None as False. Write your own boolean filter that only evaluates None as False and try this again.
Do something like this:

```
def noNone(seq):
    if all(map(lambda x: x != None, seq)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be obtained with an explicit comprehension instead of `all`, because `all` tests values to `False` and both `0` and `None` eval to `False` in a boolean context:

```
[int(all((a is not None for a in sub))) for sub in zip(*lists_for_filtering)]
```